# Getting Invalid schema name error on postgresql RDS after upgrading from 9.3 to 9.4

Tags: postgresql, yii, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, yii1.x

As pointed by amazon that PostgreSQL **9.3** is deprecated and need to upgrade our version of PostgreSQL to upper version, we just upgraded our version to **9.4**. But after upgrade we are not able to do any `save()` operation from your `Yii 1.1` project locally but the operation is working fine from the server.

When we try to run our project from locally and connect the remote PostgreSQL, we got the below error.

> {"error":"SQLSTATE[3F000]: Invalid schema name: 7 ERROR:  schema
>   \"publicubfo06sm23qicfa8kmm0nrv3td81qf928i\" does not
>   exist","try":"end"}

When I try to see my existing schemas using,

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
```

I got 3 values namely **'public','pg_catalog', 'information_schema'**

Also want to mention that previously with our version 9.3 we were able to do model operations on **Yii 1.1** like `$model->save()` and then immediately get back the primary  key value using `$model->id` or `$model->getPrimaryKey()` but now it is not working. Only the `$lastId = Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID('tbl_user_group_id_seq');` way is working now.

Can anyone point me out what is the reason behind it? is something get lost while upgrading from 9.3 to 9.4 like schema, role, sequence or anything else that is causing the errors now to access my RDS from local machine.

Comment: Examine the code that produces the strange error message.

Comment: There is no such thing as `Yii 1.3`.

Comment: @rob006 yeah, my bad, actually I meant I am using the older version of Yii, The main problem is when I've upgraded my postgresql version from 9.3 to 9.4.20 engine the existing code like `$model->save()` is not working from my local pc but it is working from remote host

Comment: Did you tried to clear cache?

Comment: @rob006 no sir, but the same code is working just before upgrading to 9.4.20, that just confused me everytime

Comment: Do you setup `defaultSchema` in config?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Yes I have fixed on the Yii framework codebase to get the latest if from postgresql

Comment: @AlwaysSunny are you saying you upgraded your version of Yii?  I'm not sure I understand.  Thank you for your prompt reply, by the way.

Comment: Actually, as far as I remember I just lookup the latest github code of Yii and change on sequence part on my old framework code